# How can I handle multiple views in one url?

Tags: python, django-forms, django-views, django-urls, django-2.2

I am working on Homepage that have until now two Views for one URL
how can i handle it ?
i w'll make a Article and Form to get user information in the same page.

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = "LandingPage"

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.form_page, name='form_page'),

]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.utils import timezone
from multiurl import ContinueResolving
from .models import Article
from .forms import UserForm


# Article
def form_page(request):
    posts = Article.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('published_date')
    return render(request, 'LandingPage/form_page.html', {'posts': posts})

# Add User
def user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('LandingPage:form_page')
    else:
        form = UserForm()
    return render(request, 'LandingPage/user.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the urls.py you added is only one view (but you wrote of two).
You can combine the two view functions into one and make the same with the templates.

```py
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.utils import timezone
from multiurl import ContinueResolving
from .models import Article
from .forms import UserForm


def form_page(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('LandingPage:form_page')
    else:
        form = UserForm()
    posts = Article.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('published_date')
    return render(request, 'LandingPage/user.html', {'form': form, 'posts': posts})
```

Comment: i've tried many solutions, but it worked Thank you so much :)